# Can you use c# custom controls in a visual c++ / cli windows application form project?

Tags: c#, forms, c++-cli, controls

If you create a custom control project in c# and compile it as a dll, will you be able to use it in a Visual c++ windows application form project?

Comment: Have you tried? If not, what potential problems are you expecting?

Comment: Wait, i just realised it works, but somehow my dll in the same project is conflicting with it, though it has nothing to do with it, it is complaining about my dll's manifest file, any idea why?

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to ask the question you meant to ask (edit your question, instead of commenting on it), and including relevant details such as the manifest file and the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

creata a custom control as a COM/ActiveX wrapper and make it  comvisible true. create a .tbl file from it  and use it vc++ apps.

please see ... http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/build-and-deploy-a-.net-com-assembly/

Answer (score -1):

No, you couldnt use it. C# code is compiled into IL code (requires .NET virtual machine), while C++ code is compiled into binary code.

Comment: That's incorrect for two reasons. Firstly, C++/CLI can be compiled to IL. Secondly, managed and unmanaged code can interact.